# How to represent a many-to-many mapping as array-field in materialized view in PostgreSQL?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-postgresql

I am trying to create materialized view in postgresql using django by following [this](https://blog.rescale.com/using-database-views-in-django-orm/) blog post.

my models are:

```
class Occasion(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ItemType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Dress(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_type = models.ForeignKey(ItemType)
    occasions = models.ManyToManyField(Occasion)
    # ... more fields
```

Now, I create a model corresponding to the materialized view (purpose of creating this view is to minimize join queries):

```
class DressMaterializedView(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_type_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # note this
    occasion_names = models.ArrayField(  # and this
        models.CharField(max_length=100)  # and compare it with Dress model above
    )
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "dresses_dressmv"
```

Now, What SQL query (ie. CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW dresses_dressmv ...) do I write to create the materialized view I intend to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `Arrayfield` provided by django OR for Django-Postgres you can have `Jsonfield` option but for that you need to use django 1.9 and postgres 9.4 mandatory

for reference you can have look at [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/)